# check box, when i tick the box the value of var does not change to 1

Tags: python, variables, checkbox, tkinter

When I click on the check box I want the value of `var1` to change to 1. However, when I do `var1.get()` in a function the value always comes up as 0.

```
var1 = IntVar()
tickbox_1 = Checkbutton(custom, text=label_1, variable=var1,)
tickbox_1.grid(row=2,column=1)
```

I have a function that is called by a button which gets the value of `var1` and prints it.

```
def custom_create():
     print(var1.get())
```

Is there anything I can do to make sure that `var1` becomes 1 when the box is ticked? Also, how can I get the box ticked when the window launches?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is substantially correct, so the cause of your problem must be in other code you haven't shown us.

FWIW, here's a small working demo.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

var1 = tk.IntVar()
var1.set(1)

tickbox_1 = tk.Checkbutton(root, text='Tick_1', variable=var1)
tickbox_1.grid(row=0, column=0)

def callback():
    print(var1.get())

b = tk.Button(root, text="Show", command=callback)
b.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

The line `var1.set(1)` makes the Checkbox start out in the ticked state.

Comment: When i var1.set(1) the value of the first tick box does show up as 1 however the box is still not ticked. The code is the same as i showed so im not too sure where the problem can be located...

Comment: @DominikPraski All I can suggest is for you to create a [mcve] that reproduces your problem and add it to the end of your question. I'll take a look at it tomorrow (it's very late in my timezone), or someone else may be able to help you in the mean time.

Answer (score -1):

I think i found where the program lays, my program is formend with many windows and the tickboxes are not in the main window (root). I want them in this secondary window and the values do not change in the second window.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()


def open_custom_gui():
    custom_gui()



b = Button(root,command=open_custom_gui)
b.grid(row=1,column=0)

def custom_gui():

    def getinfo():
        print(var1.get())

    custom= Tk()




    var1 = IntVar()

    tickbox_1 = Checkbutton(custom,text='TEST',
                                    variable=var1,)
    tickbox_1.grid(row=0,column=0)


    b = Button(custom,command=getinfo)
    b.grid(row=1,column=0)



    custom.mainloop()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer. Please don't try to update your question by posting information as if it were an answer.

Comment: What Bryan said. Either move this code to the end of your  existing question, or ask a new question. BTW, you should _never_ have two calls to `Tk()` or `.mainloop()` in a Tkinter program.